# jquery not executed

Tags: javascript, document-library, jquery, access

We are facing an issue where jQuery is not rendered the same way for users. The javascript is loaded via the master page. As a site owner I see all is well rendered but as a user with contribute rights the jquery is not executed. The jquery library is stored in a document library. If the user directly accesses the file they do not have access.

What could be causing this? Seems users don't have access to the doc library?

Answer (score 2):

There might be following scenario.

1) Check user has permission on document library. If user does not have permission then it will not load.'

2) Check is your js file is checked in or not. If it is not checked in then also it will not display to user.